# Probability of false negative in uniform distribution test

Tags: probability, distributions

Let's say I have a set of $n$ objects, and I select an object from the set with uniform probability. I do this many times, and record how many times I select each object. These counts will tend toward a uniform distribution, but an exact uniform distribution is obviously unlikely.

What's the chance that the difference between the most-selected object and least-selected object is greater than $d$? Assume I perform $s$ total selections.

If you're curious, I'm writing a test for a piece of software that should uniformly select objects in this manner, and I want to verify that it is actually selecting them uniformly. I want to know the test's false negative rate (the chance that it thinks the distribution is not uniform when it is). False negatives are significantly worse for me than false positives. If there's a better way to check if a distribution is uniform than simply comparing the max and min, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Can you say anything about the way in which - if it isn't uniform - what is likely to happen instead? Are there some kinds of non-uniformity that matter more than others? Note that the significance level (the chance that the test leads to rejection of uniformity when it's uniform) is normally chosen by the user. There are a number of common goodness of fit tests, some of which are suited to the case of discrete outcomes. Your idea may be a good way to test in many situations though it won't be as sensitive to some *particular* kinds of deviation from uniformity as some other possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately no, there isn't any particular distribution it's likely to have if it isn't uniform. The code is rather complicated, but if a certain constant is specified as 0 it reduces to a uniform distribution, and that is one case I wanted to test. If the code was wrong, though, there wouldn't really be any good way of predicting what the likely output would be.

Comment: I ended up doing some additional searching, and I'm now using something called the chi-squared test.

Comment: This chi-squared test would be a common choice for this situation but whether it would do better than your original suggestion really depends on the situation (the particular forms of nonuniformity) - this is why I was asking, in order to figure out what might be a good statistic to suggest. Since more data would (presumably) be relatively easy to get, the choice of statistic isn't perhaps especially critical in this case.

Comment: You might also consider the G test though in large samples it and the chi-square often give similar results. ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test  ... in large samples (where the expected count in each category is considerably larger than 1, say) both it and the usual Pearson chi-squared will give very close to the desired type I error rate via the chi-square approximation.